# Why is Reese allowed to have dyed hair on Malcom in the Middle?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, malcolm-in-the-middle

On the show, it's well established that Lois is a very overbearing mother who, if she doesn't like something doesn't allow it. Many episodes revolve around her irrationally forbidding one of her sons from things like, parties, sleepovers, girlfriends, mini-bikes, fireworks, etc...  It's also well established in the show she is very tight with money.

Yet, for whatever reason Reese has frosted hair. There is no episode where he dyes it the first time and she flips out. Reese's hair is just "dyed". What would the in show reason for this be?  Or, did I miss a scene in an episode between 1 and 3?

Comment: "irrationally forbidding one of her sons from things like, parties, sleepovers, girlfriends, mini-bikes, fireworks" that's not irrational; that's called good parenting. :)

Comment: I was referring to her methods.

Comment: @Mr.Manager Yup, still good parenting. Nothing wrong with a little yelling and occasional psychological torture. Unlike Hal, who is basically the head of an international drug cartel by the end of the show. Damn, that guy is the worst!

Comment: I'm generally known as the more stern/strict parent (my ex- : "they don't bicker like that at your place because they're terrified of you.").  However, I never cared about hair or clothes styles, and consciously decided that I wouldn't interfere with those choices, because I wasn't trying to make them into mini-mes.  Especially if you have a tighter grip, you need to pick and prioritize your battles.  Most parents have other things they'd rather be doing.  I offer that as a first-hand anecdote that being strong-willed doesn't exclude allowing things in other areas.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no direct in-universe mention of this (as far as I'm aware), we can only speculate.

- It's the actor's hairstyle and he's not changing it (nor did anyone ask him to).
- While Lois rules the family with an iron fist, that does not mean the micromanages them about every single choice the kids could make. If Lois ruled the family with an iron fist to the extent that you're implying in your question, none of the children would have any personal input in their own lives. Not only would that dramatically change both the characters and the vibe of the show, it's simply not possible for Lois to control everything and allow no personal freedom whatsoever. The kids still go outside and are therefore able to do something Lois doesn't like.
- She may simply be unable to stop Reese. What is she going to do if Reese gets frosted tips by himself? She probably shaves his head to teach him a lesson. But if Lois hates having a bald son more than Reese hates being bald, she can't force him to have hair without frosted tips. Reese can always have it done when he is out of the house. There are cases of the children standing up to Lois to a degree where she needs to back down, this can be one of them. Iseem to remember an episode where Reese did **this exact thing** (accepting the punishment over Lois' suggestion) and he got his way in the end. It was not about the frosted tips, but the point still stands.
- Lois focuses on presentation (personal hygiene and looking good) too. She may allow Reese's frosted tips since she considers it Reese taking care of his appearance. Even if Lois doesn't like the frosted tips, it may be key to getting Reese to care about his looks voluntarily.
- She may simply *like* Reese's frosted tips. Or she may have been swayed after Reese got the frosted tips and she saw no harm in it.

As a general rule, Lois is overbearing; but she is still human and only "acts up" about the things she cares about. While the amount of things she passionately cares about (and therefore tries to control) is certainly above average (it is her defining trait), that does not mean it is all-encompassing.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't too sure about there being an explanation, besides that Justin Berfield likely himself prefers to dye his hair.

I do vaguely recall that there is a brief dialogue between Reese and Lois while the family is having a casual morning in the kitchen. It could've actually been a conversation about how Reese slicks his hair with product.

I think it is just something that is meant to be unquestioned. Sort like how Francis and Dewey have blonde hair, though neither of their parents are blonde. You could imagine that one of the parents dyes their hair from blonde and similarly, allows Reese to as well; but me personally, I wouldn't question it.